# Experiment : Formula field is not working using <> or !=

Tags: formula-field, picklist

I am thinking maybe it something I should raise ticket to Salesforce but JIC I wrongly write the formula.

I am doing validation rule at Opportunity side comparing two picklist value, one is from Account and one is from Opportunity.The formula is simple, it just to catch if the value is not the same.If value is the same it should be able to save.

```
TEXT(Business_Division__c) <> TEXT(Account.Business_Division__c )
```

It does not work whenever I change the picklist value in Opportunity completely different from Account picklist ,it just save right away. The validation rule is ACTIVE.

To be more sure , I just add trim like below :

```
TRIM(TEXT(Business_Division__c)) <> TRIM(TEXT(Account.Business_Division__c))
```

Still not fired. I frustrated now and have no idea how to process already.
Have anyone face this issue before?

Comment: Not sure why this is not working. Can you tweak the formula like this and check? `NOT(TEXT(Business_Division__c)=TEXT(Account.Business_Division__c))`.Slightly weird solution, but lets see if it helps. Create a formula field as well with the same i.e. `NOT(TEXT(Business_Division__c)=TEXT(Account.Business_Division__c))` and see what is the formula value after saving the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because there is a trigger handling at background.This trigger is to make sure this two fields are same.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new formula field on opportunity Account_Business_Division__c = Account.Business_Division__c. Not sure about formula but in lightning component if i write soql with account. it is coming blank. You did totally correct it seems some salesforce issue this is the workaround.

```
AND(AccountId <>"",
 TEXT(Business_Division__c) <> 
 TEXT(Account_Business_Division__c)
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: Which instance you are in? I think it is a salesforce bug please keep us posted

Comment: It is stupid of me not checking first but thank you very much for the tip.